# Scope of variables inside inline function default parameter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

ES6 introduced [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). I'm trying to understand how inline function default parameters work with this new feature. Specifically how its scoping work.

Take for example the following two functions:

```
function one(x, f = function (){return x})
{
    var x = 5;
    console.log([x,f()]);
}

function two(x, f = function (){return x})
{
    x = 5;
    console.log([x,f()]);
}

one(1);//[5,1]
two(1);//[5,5]
```

Is it correct to say that, in function one, `f` keeps it's own closure scope for `x` in the parameter list, so that when the function redefines x as a new var: `var x = 5;`, the reference that `f` has, is not the same as the one inside the function?

If that's the case, is function one equal to function three below:

```
function three(x,f)
{
    var x2 = x;
    f = f !== undefined ? f : () => x2;
    var x = 5;
    console.log([x,f()]); //[5,1]
}
```

I tried, without luck, to find how this behavior is documented, if someone could point me to the right part of the documentation that would also be great.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224316/some-problems-in-function-default-parameters?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes, your description is correct. I don't think it's really documented anywhere in prose, as this use case is pretty exotic.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. In both of the top functions `x` in `f` refers to the parameter `x`.

There's some considerations with case 3.

In the third example if `f` isn't defined and you are returning `x2` when calling the function it will be equal to whatever `x` originally was. When you do `x = 5;` you aren't changing `x2`. This is because when you assign `x2 = x` JavaScript makes a copy not a reference.

**Unless** the `x` parameter is passed an `array` or `object` `x2` will be a copy and not a reference of `x`.

So if you do `three(3)` then `x2` will always be 3 because you're never changing it.

Comment: Right, I was missing the var statement for function three. With the var statements they should be the same, even with objects instead of literal values.